# CPLEX concert technology error at IloBool solve() return IloAlgorithm::solve();}

Tags: cplex

when solving a branch and bound and column generation problem with cplex concert technology, after it's solving the problem again and again, I get this error when I debugged the program. It's so strange, because the source code belongs to ilocplexi.h library at the line: IloBool solve() return IloAlgorithm::solve();}
And the error is:
Unhandled exception at 0x7515277c in temp1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: IloCplex::Exception at memory location 0x005e9d3c..

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance